# Let $p$ be a Mersenne prime and $G$ an extension of $C_p$, then we have a subgroup in which $C_p$ has a complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be an Mersenne prime, i.e. $p + 1$ is a power of $2$. Suppose $G$ is an extension of the cyclic group $C_p$ of order $p$ by a group $\overline H$ isomorphic to $PSL(2, p+1)$ or the Suzuki group $Sz(p+1)$, i.e. we have $C_p \unlhd G$ and $G / C_p \cong \overline H$.

> Then there exists a subgroup $U$ of $G$ with $(|G : U|, p) = 1$ and $C_p \le U$ and $C_p$ has a complement in $U$.

*Proof*: As $C_p$ has an abelian automorphism group and $\overline H$ is a simple non-abelian group, $C_p \le Z(G)$. Let $U$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. The image $\overline U$ of $U$ in $\overline H$ has order $p$, so $U$ is abelian of order $p^2$. There is an involution $\overline u$ in the normalizer of $\overline U$ in $\overline H$ that does not centralize $\overline U$. If $u$ is the involution of $G$ mapped onto $\overline u$, then $u$ normalizes $U$ but does not centralize it. However, $u$ centralizes $C_p$. Thus $K = \{ x \in U : x^u = x^{-1} \}$ is a complement for $C_p$ in $U$. $\square$

I do not understand this proof. As every $u \in G$ induces an automorphism by conjugation on $C_p$, and the automorphism group is abelian, I guess we must have $x^{uv} = x^{vu}$ for all $x \in C_p$ and $u,v \in G$. Now fix some $u \in G$, then it either is in the center of $G$, and we have $x^u = x$ then, or there exits some $w \in G$ with $uw \ne wu$. But does this implies that $x^u = x$ in this case too?

Also if $U$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then for its image
$$
 \overline U = UC_p / C_p \cong U / (U\cap C_p)
$$
and as $|PSL(2, p+1)| = (2^n - 1)2^n(2^n + 1)$ with $p+1 = 2^n$, the highest $p$-power dividing $|PSL(2, p+1)|$ is $p$ itself, hence $\overline U$ has order $p$, which shows that $|U| \le |\overline U||C_p| = p^2$, and as $p^2$ divides $|G|$ (as it divides $C_p$ and $G/C_p$) we must have $|U| = p^2$ and $U$ is thus abelian. Further as $p = |\overline U| = |U||U\cap C_p|$ this gives $|U\cap C_p| = p$, hence $C_p \le U$.

Again if $\overline U$ is a subgroup of $PSL(2, p+1)$, then I guess its normalizer is a dihedral group, so we can take some reflection $\overline u$, which is non-central and an involution. But why is its preimage $u$ also an involution, the assumption just said that $u^2 \in C_p$, but why $u^2 = 1$ and why $u \in N_G(U)$ but $u \notin C_G(U)$?

Also why is $K$ a complement of $C_p$ in $U$. I see as $x^u = x$ for $x \in C_p$, and we have no involution, i.e. no element that is its own inverse, in $U$, we have $C_p \cap K = 1$. As $|U| = p^2$, we would have $KC_p = u$ if $K \ne 1$, but why is $K$ non-empty, i.e. there exists some $x \in U$ with $x^u = x^{-1}$?

**EDIT** (15 January 2016): Now I had solved one questions, namely that $u$ is an involution in $G$, but still I do not see why $Z(G) \le C_p$ and $u \in N_G(U)$, but $u \notin C_G(U)$, I am not sure that the normalizer of $\overline U$ in $\overline H$ has an involution and that $K$ is a complement. I append some thougths

i) $C_p \le Z(G)$

As $\overline H$ is non-nonabelian and simple we have $Z(G)C_p / C_p = \overline 1$, hence $Z(G) \le C_p$. Also $C_p / Z(C_p) \cong \mbox{Inn}(C_p)$ is trivial, but we want that $C_p / Z(G)$, i.e. the inner automorphisms induced by $C_p$, is trivial. But I still do not see how to do that.

ii) $u^2 = 1$. The only question solved by now.

Suppose $u^2 = x$ with $x \ne 1$, then $\langle u^2 \rangle = C_p$, and as squaring is an automorphism in $C_p$ we have $\langle u \rangle = \langle u^2 \rangle$, hence $u \in C_p$, but then $u$ would be the identity in $\overline H$, contradicting the fact that it is an involution in $\overline H$.